# What query do I need to determine if a user has favourited another?

Tags: php, mysql

I apologise for the simpleton question but I am having a complete blank, hence why the wording of the title is vague.

I have built a simple PHP/MySQL user favouriting system that works fine, except for one part. Once the user has favourited another user, I cannot think for the life of me how to show the user that they have already favourited that user.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (($user_data['username'] == $profile_data['username']) === false) { 
   if () { ?>
       // Favourite user        
<?php } else { ?>
       //See whether favourited or unfavourite user                 
<?php } } ?>
```

The table structure of `favourites` is simply two columns, `favouritee` being the profile favourited and `favouriter` being the current user favouriting. This table is joined to a main `users` table and the columns are populated by username strings.

**EDIT**

This is what I have got so far:

```
$username = $user_data['username'];
$favouritee = $profile_data['username'];

$check_fav = mysqli_query("SELECT `id` FROM `favourites` WHERE (`favouritee` = '$favouritee' AND `favouriter` = '$username')");

if (mysqli_num_rows($check_fav) == 1) {
           // Favourite user    
} else {
           //See whether favourited or unfavourite user                 
}
```

Comment: could you provide a little more code & db structure ?

Comment: I don't think it is particularly clear what you are stuck on. Do you have a table structure designed for this? If so, would you edit it into your question? Are you looking for a query to check whether one user has favourited another, or is this a UI design issue?

Comment: @halfer I apologise, I know the question is ambiguous, but I am looking for a query to see whether one user has favourited another.

Comment: Your edit still needs work I think - are the two columns integer foreign keys, or string user-names? Do you also have a `user` table that this points to?

Comment: Try actually writing a query and THEN come back for help. You won't learn if you just get stuff handed to you. What's your best guess?

Comment: How are you getting on with this, @britedesigns?

Comment: @halfer See my final edit, that works as it should now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. I've moved it to a new answer - if you self-solve in the future we encourage OPs to write their own answers, and to accept them with the green tick. Also, when someone helps you, please do answer them, as it helps foster the community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*:

Working code:

```
if (($user_data['username'] == $profile_data['username']) === false) {

   $username = $user_data['username'];
   $favouritee = $profile_data['username'];

   $check_fav = mysqli_query("SELECT `id` FROM `favourites` WHERE (`favouritee` = '$favouritee' AND `favouriter` = '$username')");

      if (mysqli_num_rows($check_fav) == 1) {
         // Favourite user 
      } else {
        // Unfavourited/check
      }                     
   }
```

Comment: I wonder if this is susceptible to SQL injection - if you are using MySQLi it is trivial to parameterise the two equality clauses.

Answer (score 0):

To find whether a user has favourited another user, assume `$myUsername` as the logged-in user's username from the session, and assume `$otherUsername` coming from a profile page of another user (or perhaps a paged list of users).

```
SELECT 1 FROM favourite
WHERE favouriter = :favouriter AND favouritee = :favouritee
```

You can then inject parameters `$myUsername` into `:favouriter` and `$otherUsername` into `:favouritee` and if you get a row, you already have a favourite connection, and if you get zero rows, there is no favourite connection.

This is just the raw query, so of course you'll need to add PHP database code around this. If you're not familiar with this, take a look at the docs for PDO or MySQLi at php.net - both sections will give enough information to get you up and running.

That said, assuming usernames are stored in the `user` table, I'd be inclined to switch the two columns in the `favourite` table to integer foreign keys - it'll be faster and will save disk space. I'd call these `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` to make it clear what they are foreign keys of, and the direction of the favourite.

Comment: `favouriter = :favouriter` , is that `mysql` syntax?

Comment: @Noob: it's not MySQL SQL syntax, no; it's syntax for the PDO driver. [See here for an example](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).